# Swift 4: Issues passing data from one NSViewController to another

Tags: swift, nstextview, nsviewcontroller, nsmutablestring, nstextstorage

In a macOS app I am attempting to have a sheet popup where the user can input text.  Once the user add's text they click save closing the sheet and adding the text to the previous pages NSTextView. I have tried many variations of this but I'm honestly not even sure how to pass data between two ViewControllers.  I have tried PerformSegue which appears to be iOS only.  I've also tried saving to a UserDefaults().string(forKey:"") but nothing seems to work.  Finally I have come across a way to reference the other ViewController class and then run a function from that class but it doesn't appear to be working.  Here is the code I have so far(I tried to add all the relevant code if something is missing let me know).

This is the ViewContoller connected to the View I want to add the text to.

```
class NotesViewController: NSViewController {

override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)
}

@IBOutlet var notesTextView: NSTextView!

func updateCaseTemplate(template: Any) {
    notesTextView.textStorage?.mutableString.setString(template as! String)
}
```

This is the ViewController where I am trying to get the users text.

```
class TemplateViewController: NSViewController {

private var notesView: NotesViewController?

@IBOutlet weak var notesTemplateTextView: NSTextView!


@IBAction func saveNotesTemplate(_ sender: Any) {
    var notesTemplate = notesTemplateTextView.textStorage?.mutableString
    notesView?.updateCaseTemplate(template: notesTemplate!)
    dismissViewController(self)
}


}
```

I am able to run a print(notesTemplate!) in saveNotesTemplate and it is showing the correct text from the NSTextView!. If I put a Break on the func updateCaseTemplate() it never gets to it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am really trying to learn here and I have google'd everything I could trying to find a solution to this.

Finally, if am doing this completely wrong and there is a better way please let me know.

Comment: Add to your question that you can't give a complete, working example, because there's just too much boilerplate code to make this part of the UI work. Someone will scold you for not posting a complete, working example. Part of the rules and all. I'd say just before the first block of code.

Comment: Just explain I can't give a complete working example? Or is there more code I could include to make it more clear what I am trying to accomplish?  I appreciate the feedback I am new to stack overflow and coding in general.

Comment: About your problem: are you saying you do get into `saveNotesTemplate()`? But you can't reach the call to `updateCaseTemplate()`

Comment: The rules require that you post something that people can copy/paste into their own editors, then compile and run it and see the problem you're talking about. You can't do that with the part of the UI you're doing. You'd have to paste 500 lines of code. I was worried someone would give you a hard time, but it looks you're in the clear. The people who would harass you would usually be here by now.

Comment: saveNotesTemplate() appears to work fine.  I have put in a print(notesTemplate!) before the dismissViewController(self) and it will output the correct data from the NSTextView and close the sheet but nothing ever loads in the other ViewController.  I've tried putting a Break on the updateCaseTemplate function and a print() inside that function and seems like its never even being loaded.

Comment: You name your NSView subclass 'NotesViewController'?  There's something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @kiddslopp And you've already checked for obvious stuff like `notesView == nil`, or `textStorage == nil`?

Comment: It was supposed to NSViewController not NSView.  Not sure what you mean by fundamentally wrong though.  Sorry I am new.

Comment: @GreatBigBore If either was nil I wouldn't be able to print(notesTemplate!).  I honestly seems like function from the other ViewController isn't being ran at all.  But I am definitely new to all this.

Comment: Sorry, not `textStorage`, but definitely `notesView`. You could `print(notesTemplate)` without that.

Comment: Alright well notesView is definitely nil if I try print(notesView).  I guess I assumed that since I was able to type notesView?. and it would autocomplete give me updateCaseTempate as an option is was connecting to that ViewController.  If thats not the case then that would be my problem I just have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: Yeah, you can't use autocomplete to tell you about things that will happen while the app is running, like connecting view controllers. autocomplete only knows what's going on while you're actually typing. Unfortunately, you've gone beyond my expertise. But I think you can get a lot of help by googling for tutorials on how to write a Mac app. They always start with the UI, and hopefully you can learn enough from that. You might also try posting to a site with "forum" in the name. The format is better for conversations like this, and the rules usually aren't as strict. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Hey, change your title to "NSViewController doesn't load". You'll attract more people with it. Be well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass data between view controllers, you need to have a variable in the second view controller that can take what you want to pass. Then, you need to send it when you prepare to segue.

For example, This shows passing data from firstVC to secondVC when goToNext is tapped (which I've made a navigation button here)

**FirstVC**

```
import UIKit

class FirstVC: UIViewController {

// MARK: - Properties
var user: UserProfile? // build it from a function
var note: Note?  // build or use none

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    getUser()
    if note == nil {
        getNote()   
    }
    setupStack()
}
override func viewDidLoad(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad(true)

    makeBarItems()
    setupStack()
}

// MARK: - Setup

func makeBarItems(){

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named:"list-fat-7"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(goToNextTapped))
}

func setupStack() {
// maybe you have data in a stack
}

@objc func goToNextTapped (){
    print("goToNextTapped")

    let detailVC: SecondVC? = SecondVC()

    if detailVC != nil {
        print("setting up secondVC")
        detailVC?.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

        detailVC?.note = selectedNote
        detailVC?.user = user!

        present(detailVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
}
```

**SecondVC**

```
import UIKit

class SecondVC: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    var user: UserProfile? // get from firstvc
    var note: Note? = "NONE" // get it from first vc or use none

    // blah rest of secondVC
    }
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need.  Is it the exact same process for going the opposite way?  I am trying to go from the SecondViewController back to the the First.  Also I see you are using UIKit and UIViewController.  I am trying to do this with a macOS StoryBoard app.  Is the procedure the same?

Comment: It works the same both ways. However, I never use the StoryBoard (because it is an absolute mess with version control). Essentially, you will need to do the same thing but probably pass the data in your "prepare for segue" function.